# TYPO3 Extbase contrain date in Domain Object Model

Tags: validation, extbase, typo3-8.x

I have a model class with start date and end date. I want to make sure that the start date is always less than the end date.

I thought I might achieve this with an `@validate` annotation in the model class and a custom validator class [like in the docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8.7/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html).

How can I get access to the start date value in the validate function?

```
<?php

namespace XXX\YYY\Domain\Model\Validator;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class EventEndDateValidator extends AbstractValidator
{
    public function validate($endDate)
    {
       return;
        $this->addError('Validator cant do anything yet.', 42);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even Typo3 doesn't provide This type of functionalities,
You can test in  start_date and end_date in  "Access" in any typo3 default element.

For this, you should use **the hook** and compare dates while user **save record**,
and return false with the error message.

Let me know if you need any help related to hook

Thanks!!

Comment: Super Thanks! I wrote my first hook code a few days ago in another context and did not see the common context. Your approach seems totally plausible to me. A great resource for hooks are the pages of Andre Rinas: https://www.andrerinas.de/tutorials/typo3-alle-aftersave-hooks-im-ueberblick-62-76lts.html and this: http://www.interaktionsdesigner.de/2008/processdatamap_postprocessfieldarray from Paul Lunow. The examples worked instantly for me.